# Solve for x with exact values

Tags: logarithms

I am super confused how does this step end up with this?

[image]

Then this is the working, I dont understand the second step please help me to show the missing step any Law of Logarithms at work here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the second step, both sides of the equation are multiplied by $e^{3x}$.  In the third step, $2 \cdot e^{3x}$ is subtracted from both sides of the equation.  It can be rephrased as a quadratic equation in $y$ where $y = e^{-3x}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this might be easier to follow using substitution.

With the substitution, $y=e^{3x}$ (forcing $y>0$), this becomes
$$
\begin{align}
y-8/y&=2\tag1\\
y^2-2y-8&=0\tag2\\
y&=1\pm3\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1):}$ substitution
$\text{(2):}$ algebra
$\text{(3):}$ [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation)

Therefore, $e^{3x}=4\Rightarrow x=\frac23\log(2)$.